# How can I check what mode is already on on defaults write?

Tags: macos, defaults

I am making a script that puts on a `defaults write` thing to `true`. How can I check before it's it's `true` or `false`?

Comment: `defaults read` ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaults read. For example, if I wanted to check for `AppleShowAllFiles`, I would do:

```
~$ defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles
YES
```

Which would return `YES` in the stdout. You can make your script execute this command and read it from stdout.

Another perhaps unrealistic (and quite dangerous) option would be to read directly from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.<ID>.plist`, however most of then are rather unreadable. For example, `com.apple.Finder.plist` around the area of `AppleShowAllFiles` looks like this:

```
NSNavOutlineColumnSettings.v1_FXMyDocumentsArrangeGroupViewBy_AppleShowAllFiles_ViewSettingsDictionary_CopyProgressWindowLocation_FK_StandardViewSettings_8NSTableView Hidden Columns
```

This is not recommended though

Comment: I would say - always stick with `defaults read`. That layer is there to protect you from underlying storage changes. If Apple moves the place where they store a specific key or cache it in a database file, you will miss that if you are parsing a file from the filesystem.

Comment: It somewhat funny you picked `AppleShowAllFiles` for your example because by default it does not exist and the output is `The domain/default pair of (com.apple.Finder, AppleShowAllFiles) does not exist` when it doesn't. :)